# Bring Filter in RDL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created a RDL in SSRS which shows a Chart. I want tp apply Filter in this chart ie I want to bring a Text Box in the RDL, for entering DepartmentName in the RDL, while previewing and render the chart based on the value entered in the Text Box. How will I bring this filter ? I saw a property called Filter, when I right clicked on Dataset, at left pane.

Answer (score 0):

Filter mean the fields that needs to be displayed?? If thats wat you are asking then you need to dynamically create RDL files based on the fileds selected in the dataset. Check this example http://www.gotreportviewer.com/DynamicTable.zip

Comment: No. The field is already displayed in the chart. The data under that field is displayed in the chart. I need to filter this chart by this field ie based on the value entered in this text box

Comment: Ok tat can be done by using Expressions. You should build an expression to do logical processing of data tat needs to be displayed. Expression should be built. Right click on the field and select Expression and build ur expresssion there. Expressions are similar to VBS . Example =iif(IsNothing(Fields!Result.Value),"",First(Fields!Result_ID.Value)) In this example i'm checking for the presence of the data in the Result field , if data is empty the Result_ID field is shown as empty else data is populated....